# How to get CherryPy to listen only on a specific host

Tags: python, flask, webserver, wsgi, cherrypy

I have a flask app that I want to deploy using CherryPy's built in server. I chose CherryPy so that the app can be deployed without having to reverse proxy (ie. nginx in front).

I'm having trouble getting CherryPy to listen for requests on just a single hostname.

Say I'm serving 2 sites: test1.com and test2.com (and have them set in my hosts file to point back to localhost).
My `/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1    test1.com test2.com
```

CherryPy is serving `test1.com`, `test2.com` doesn't have anything serving it.

My cherrypy file is as follows:

```
import cherrypy

from my_test_flask_app import app

if __name__ == '__main__':

    cherrypy.tree.graft(app, "/")

    cherrypy.server.unsubscribe()

    server = cherrypy._cpserver.Server()

    server.socket_host = "test1.com"
    server.socket_port = 8030
    server.thread_pool = 30

    server.subscribe()

    cherrypy.engine.start()
    cherrypy.engine.block()
```

Set up this way, I go to `test1.com:8030` on my browser and it works as expected.

But when I go to `test2.com:8030`, the same app is served. I expected it not to serve anything, since CherryPy isn't set up to listen for `test2.com`.

To me, it seems that CherryPy is just listening for everything on the given port (8030), and treating the `socket_host` part as if its `0.0.0.0`

Am I missing something here? I've looked through lots of docs and tutorials, but all things suggest that this code snippet should be working as I expected.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can setup what you want...

```
root = Root()
RootApp = cherrypy.Application(root)
Domain2App = cherrypy.Application(root)
SecureApp = cherrypy.Application(Secure())

vhost = cherrypy._cpwsgi.VirtualHost(RootApp,
    domains={'www.domain2.example': Domain2App,
             'www.domain2.example:443': SecureApp,
             })

cherrypy.tree.graft(vhost)
```

https://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/3.3.0/refman/_cpwsgi.html#classes

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! That lead me to the right direction. Had to make some minor mods for the flask app situation, and plugged in 'None' to VirtualHost's first argument so that it wouldn't serve a default app.

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstand the socket listen address - they are IP addresses only, not on DNS names. Set this way, CherryPy listens to the localhost (127.0.0.1) only - try using your Ethernet/Wlan local address and you should get connection refused.

Also, you can wrap your application with a WSGI middleware that checks the Host header for the proper domain, or use CherryPy virtual host facility to check the host header.

Comment: Thanks. Virtual host facility was the way to go for me. Didn't know about it being IP address only (socket_host was a little misleading), but makes sense.

Comment: No, the "Host" HTTP header is the misleading naming